# getCanonicalName() returns null when running in a different Java version

Tags: java

```
public class MyClass{
    public void action() {
    }
    public void test(){
        MyClassNameTest.takeAction(this::action);
    }
}

public interface MyInterface {
    public void action();
    default void printClassName(){
        System.out.println("java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("getCanonicalName: " + getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("getName: " + getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("isAnonymousClass: " + getClass().isAnonymousClass());
    }
}
```

Run this class:

```
public class MyClassNameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass().test();
    }
    static void takeAction(MyInterface myInterface) {
        myInterface.printClassName();
        myInterface.action();
    }
}
```

## Steps to Reproduce

1. compile above classes in java 1.8 or 11
2. run MyClassNameTest in java 15 or above

## Current result

`getClass().getCanonicalName()` returns null

If you run them in the same Java version as you compiled, `getCanonicalName()` returns a non-null string.

I found the interesting result, but I don't know the reason. Does anyone know?

Comment: Just wondering, but is the relative convolution of the code necessary to reproduce the problem? Or can it be reproduced with e.g., only one class and a functional interface implemented via a method reference?

Comment: @Slaw: I could reproduce the result by simply doing `Runnable r = () -> {}; System.out.println(r.getClass().getCanonicalName());`. That prints some internal class name in Java 11 and null in Java 17.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of investigation, it is apparently because since Java 15, method references and lambdas (or rather, `invokedynamic`) are now implemented using [hidden classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/371), at least in the OpenJDK. In short, hidden classes are classes that are defined dynamically at runtime, using [`Lookup.defineHiddenClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineHiddenClass(byte%5B%5D,boolean,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption...)), has no binary name, and does not need a class loader to be loaded.

Try also printing `getClass().isHidden()` in `printClassName`. It should print `true`.

You can also compare the [Java 15 implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java#L382) of `InnerClassLambdaMetafactory` vs the [Java 8 implementation](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java#l324). The latter uses the deprecated `sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass`.

According to the JEP that introduced hidden classes, which was also implemented in Java 15, `getCanonicalName` returning null is the expected behaviour:

> Via the `Class` object, the hidden class can be instantiated and its members accessed as if it was a normal class, except for four restrictions:
>
> 1. `Class::getName` returns a string that is not a binary name, as described earlier.
> 2. `Class::getCanonicalName` returns null, indicating the hidden class has no canonical name. (Note that the `Class` object for an anonymous class in the Java language has the same behavior.)
> 3. [...]

At the end of the day, the objects produced by a method reference expression only has the guarantees stated in [this section of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3). The implementation could change at any moment, and this case is exactly an example of that.